# Stokes' Theorem and Surface Independence Failure

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

As we know, if $\vec{F}=\nabla\times\vec{A}$ then from Stokes' Theorem, $\iint_{S_1} \vec{F}\dot \,d\vec{S}=\iint_{S_2}\vec{F}\dot \,d\vec{S}$ where $S_1$ and $S_2$ have the same boundary.

Does anyone have a quick example at the top of their head wherein the above equality is not satisfied implying that the vector potential of $\vec{F}$ does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like the inverse-square field
$$
F(x, y, z) = \frac{(x, y, z)}{(x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2})^{3/2}},\quad
(x, y, z) \neq (0, 0, 0),
$$
whose divergence vanishes identically, and $S$ the unit sphere, cut into any convenient pair of surfaces, e.g., the upper and lower hemispheres? (The integral of $F$ over $S$ with the outward unit normal is $4\pi$, not $0$.)

Comment: but i'm referring to the flux of the curl of $F$.

Comment: It's possible I misunderstood your question. There exist vector fields $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$ defined on, say, the complement of the positive $z$-axis and the complement of the negative $z$-axis, such that $\nabla \times A_{i} = F$. (This is not trivial, but follows because $\nabla \cdot F = 0$, and the indicated regions are contractible.) But since $F$ has non-zero flux over the unit sphere, there is no vector field $A$ on the complement of the origin such that $F = \nabla \times A$.

Comment: Alright! I get what you mean. But I guess you can't take the cut at the middle because otherwise the flux across each hemisphere would be $2\pi.$ But somewhere above or below the plane $z=0$ would be just nice.

Comment: You're very welcome. Incidentally, cutting in the middle is all right; check the respective directions of boundary traversal and corresponding surface normals. :)

Comment: Yes I see, there's a difference in the sign!

Comment: By the way, I think you meant that the divergence does not vanish!

Comment: The divergence really does vanish everywhere except the origin. If it didn't, this example wouldn't be interesting: There would be no reason to "expect" (i) $F$ to be the curl of another field $A$ or (ii) the flux of $F$ across a surface to depend only on the boundary, etc.